# On premises AD to Azure AD:Attribute mapping

Tags: active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory

I am able to successfully sync accounts but am finding that on-premise attributes are getting mapped to the accounts' Azure AD doppelganger in very odd ways. For example the Azure account field called 'Office Number' (under Work Info > job info) is being populated with the physicaldeliveryOfficeName attribute in on-premise AD (which my company uses to list sub-departments for some reason).

According to the official 'what is mapped' list from MS ([here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19901.dirsync-list-of-attributes-that-are-synced-by-the-azure-active-directory-sync-tool.aspx)) this attribute is not mapped to anything unusual in Azure. What's more, this page doesn't list 'Office Number' at all. I assumed that was pulled from 'telephoneNumber' in AD but apparently not? After the account is synced it is read-only in Azure. Why would 'Office Number' be pulling from such an obscure attribute? I cannot find anywhere this has been (or even can be) customized.

[image: Image showing the Office Number field being populated incorrectly]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this in AADSync by using the Sync Rules Editor if you want to flow alternates in to these fields.